# Alternatives to join on Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have two Spark dataframes that are each 539 million rows and 4 columns. columns A and B are strings and columns C,D, E and F are floats

```
DF1
-----------------
A      B     C      D
"A1"  "B1"  1.1    1.2
"A2"  "B2"  1.3    1.4

DF2
-----------------
A      B     E      F
"A1"  "B1"  2.1    2.2
"A2"  "B2"  2.3    2.4
```

I would like to join DF1 (539 million rows) and DF2 (also 539 million rows). I tried DF1.join(DF2,, "fullouter") on 50 node cluster and 8 GB executor memory. It automatically terminates the cluster with out-of-memory error message.

Are there alternatives to join with rdds, or datasets that are memory efficient than the df.join()?

Comment: I think you haven't mentioned the common key for both the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following

1. Compression as been used.
2. Join condition is present.
3. Check you **driver program heap memory** from the spark UI and change it.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check following:
1) How have you partitioned your data
2) how many executors have you assigned based on number of partitions
3) As mentioned above: the driver memory